VSCode Live Server typo in address
I'm not sure why, but when Live Server goes live for me, it always resolves the http address without the colon.
VSCode HTTP Typo
I've looked through the settings.json for Live Server and I don't see anywhere that I can change this. My liveServer.settings.host is set to "http://127.0.0.1". If I change this, it changes what loads, but I cannot get it to include the colon. What am I missing?

Check this out: 
And don't write http://


What am I missing?

That a host does not include a protocol. http is a protocol. Instead of http://127.0.0.1, you should be putting 127.0.0.1.
